# How to JOIN two SQL tables from the front end/ what REST api would i use

Tags: sql, node.js, rest

This probably is a two part question. So What I'm wanting to do is have to tables JOIN by their ID's but when I want that join to happen would be with a function from the front end (IE a button click or something similar). But what I'm wondering is what is the REST command I would use for wanting to do something like this? I'm thinking GET? and also if it is how would I pass two Id's to the back end with the request? I understand how to do one parameter with:

```
this.testName = function(id) {
return $http({
      method: 'GET',
  url: '/api/order/:id'
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  return response.data
});
```

};

I would think it would be as simple as passing in a second parameter , but I'm not sure what I need to make my url in node to pass in two separate id's. 
Any and all help appreciated, if I'm overthinking this please slap some sense into me!

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking correctly. Create and endpoint to return what you want based on your request.

To pass two ids try something like this:

```
url: '/api/order/:orderId/otherId/:otherId'
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, One thing I forgot to mention is it's going to be two tables columns in the same table ( just different id's) do you think in that case I could just use a query?

Comment: Can you give an example of the data?

Comment: its going to be pretty simple the table is just going to be an  auto incrementing ID and a column to take in text. I want to be able to do an (INNER?) JOIN on two of the ID to show two columns of the data together. So just a way to compare two of bodies of text together